# Fetch text from file and input into a specific div in a webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to have a txt file with some HTML code in it, for example:
`<p>Hi</p>
<p>Hello</p>`
and use JavaScript or PHP to read the code and input it into a specific div in the HTML document. Or if there is another, better way of editing the HTML code for a page header for example in a txt file and the header changes on every page on the site, please let me know as I do not want to have to go through to every file changing things like this every time I make a small change to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using php :

```
$content = file_get_contents('path/to/your/file.txt');
echo $content;
```

Edit to answer to @bakriawad about the xml file,
You could use something like this :

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "URL/TO/file.xml",
   dataType: "xml",
   success: function(xml){
      $('#myDiv').html($(xml).html());
   },
   error: function() {
      alert("An error occurred while reading XML file.");
   }
});
```

file.xml should looks like this :

```
<document>
  <p>Hi</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
</document>
```

Comment: you could use XML to have many contents and read from within the tags, would be nice if you can show the way too.

Comment: If this answers your question mark it. Too many people use this website to get free source code and don't mark the question. To show appreciation mark the answer, it really isn't hard.